# React Native + Django DRF network error on POST

Tags: python, reactjs, django, react-native, django-rest-framework

I'm developing a React Native app. As a backend I'm using DJango DRF. I'm trying to make  POST request for creating a new element on backend, this is my code in React:

```
**API.JS**
const routes = {
  accounts: {
    get: () =>
      requestHelper({
        method: "get",
        url: "accounts/",
      }),
    post: (data) =>
      requestHelper({
        data,
        method: "post",
        url: "accounts/",
      }),
  },
};

**API CALL**
const formData = new FormData();

const image = {
  uri: data.image,
  name: data.timestamp + ".jpg",
  type: "image/jpeg",
};

_.map(data, (item, name) => {
   formData.append(name, item);
});
    
formData.append("image", image);

await api.accounts
    .post(formData)
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res, "OK");
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};
```

Te request is reaching backend and the new Account is being created on database (including the image). The problem is that,despite that Django is returning 200_OK, the api call is going to the catch statement, and this error appears on console:

> Network Error
>
> Stack trace:   node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:15:0 in
>    node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:81:4 in
> dispatchXhrRequest
> node_modules/event-target-shim/dist/event-target-shim.js:818:20 in
> EventTarget.prototype.dispatchEvent
> node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network/XMLHttpRequest.js:575:10
> in setReadyState
> node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network/XMLHttpRequest.js:389:6 in
> __didCompleteResponse   node_modules/react-native/Libraries/vendor/emitter/EventEmitter.js:189:10
> in emit
> node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:425:19
> in __callFunction
> node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:112:6
> in __guard$argument_0
> node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:373:10
> in __guard
> node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:111:4
> in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue   [native code]:null in
> callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue

I think is not an Image problem, because I've removed for testing and same error appears.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you get the `Network Error` when the REST API server can't be reached. Have you set the correct `baseURL` or `proxy` to the Django server? Django server is probably running on `8000` and React is running by default on `3000`.

The fact that you see a request on the server-side is a little strange. It will suggest that there might be a bug/problem in the code that is used to process a successful response. Have you tried to remove that code? Yes, might sound strange, just remove the `console.log(res, "OK");` and see what will happen?

Comment: Hi pplonski. Thanks for your answer. the baseURL is correctly configured, otherwise the Account wouldn't be created. The request is reaching backend just fine (Django console shows a 200 response to the request)

[04/Nov/2020 14:29:52] "POST /api/accounts/ HTTP/1.1" 200 12438

Don't understand why axios is entering to catch statement if Django returns a 200_OK

Comment: Can you show the code to reproduce it? There might be an error on js side, and the error will be raised even if server responded with 200.

Comment: Yes of course, but how can I show you the entire code?

Comment: Please create github repo, with steps how to run app